# How can I re-install Windows 10 on a GPT drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, motherboard, mbr

My motherboard is GA-970-UD3 with Phenom II x4 955
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
I have just fitted a 4Tb Seagate Barracuda as my 1Tb Barracuda had failed after around 6 years.

12 gig memory (3 x 4gig all same make, model and spec)
I can install Windows 10 using media creation on USB stick but setup says that it will only install to MBR and so I've had to do that.
As a result I can only access 2 Tb of the drive.
What am I doing wrong? I would like to install to the 4 Tb setup as GPT

Thanks

Comment: Go into the BIOS and look for a UEFI [CSM enable/disable]/both/legacy BIOS only setting. If you set it to 'both', it will accept either MBR or GPT.

Comment: @cybernard Sure, but we don't want BIOS mode anyway unless the machine has BIOS. And because Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode in UEFI hardware still requires MBR the OP is limited to 2TB partitions, something they don't want, apparently. So, the actual option is UEFI/GPT as I indicated in the answer. Another "problem" with both is that then it'll depend on how the installer is booted - there'll be 2 options, "UEFI: USB name" and "USB name", for the boot selection for the same USB stick; how it boots is how it installs. Better do the thing right from the start, disable CSM and prepare the drive as GPT.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicating it's only possible to install in MBR (and consequently in the Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode you DON'T want irrespective of the additional problem of the 2TB per partition limitation) is because the drive is already partitioned / has a partition table as the old and obsolete 'msdos' (MBR) of the 1980's.

You should prepare the drive as GPT before the actual installation takes place. There are a few methods to do that but, ironically, the faster as arguably easier one is by **booting a mainstream Linux live session (e.g. Ubuntu), running `GParted` an there select the drive in the rightmost dropdown menu, then in GParted's menus go to Device > Create new partition table... > choose "GPT" and commit changes.**

You can also do it directly from the Windows 10 (or 8.x or 11) installer in command prompt:

1. To open the command prompt during Windows®10 installation, press Shift + F10.
2. Type command: `diskpart` (to open the utility).
3. Type command: `list disk` (to show the disks available).
4. Verify what is the **desired drive to be used as boot drive**.
5. Ask to type command: `select disk` <the number of drive from step 4>.
6. Type command: `clean` (this initializes the drive, and you should wait for it to finish - please note this **will erase ALL data in that drive**).
7. Type command: `convert gpt` (This will convert the partition table and a message saying it worked will show up).
8. Type command: `exit` or close the command prompt with the "X" at the top right corner.
9. Click the "refresh" button and try to install Windows® 10 on the target disk again.

Source: https://www.solidigm.com/support-page/installation-compatibility/ka-00046.html

Additional notes:

- The aforementioned steps were copied almost verbatim from the source but corrected where appropriate, it has some minor mistakes, namely...
- In step #5 they mention "the number of drive from step 5", obviously incorrect because they're referring to the previous step which is #4;
- In step #6 the original text says "(this *formats* the drive (...)) which is incorrect. Strictly speaking format implies the creation of a file system but that can only happen after the partitioning is chosen / the partition table table is created i.e. after choosing MBR or GPT. Only then one or more partitions with specific file systems (e.g. NTFS, exFAT, etc.) can be created -and- formatted. This, obviously, should be done by the Windows installer itself, either automatically (will use the entire drive) or by manually creating the necessary partitions.

Comment: Thanks. I will go away and try this and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately windows setup wont allow a GPT installation. Thank you anyway. I will try to access the spare 2T another way.

Comment: It does, it must, it's the only way for Windows 11 and the strongly recommended way for anything since Windows8! So, probably you're doing something wrong. Make sure CSM/Legacy is disabled in UEFI settings in order to avoid inadvertently boot in legacy mode because **how it boots is how it installs**. That's all there is, honestly. If this is too much for you then ask a professional to do it.